# Github GraphQL - Getting a repository's list of commits

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I am using GraphQL to get some data from a list of repositories using Github's GraphQL (v4) API. I want to get a list of the **latest commits** from a repository, no matter what is the commit's branch/tag/ref.

For now I am doing the following to get the list of commits from a certain repository:

```graphql
... on Repository{
    refs(refPrefix:"refs/",orderBy:$refOrder,first:1){
        edges{
            node{
                ... on Ref{
                    target{
                        ... on Commit{
                            history(first:10){
                                totalCount
                                edges{
                                    node{
                                        ... on Commit{
                                            committedDate
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `$refOrder` is an object I am sending together with the request and it is defined below:

```json
{
    "refOrder": {
        "direction": "DESC",
        "field": "TAG_COMMIT_DATE"
    }
}
```

This piece of code is working, but not retrieving the results I want. The response comes back with a list of commits, **but not necessarily the last commits from the repository**. When I go to the repository page and click on "Commits", I usually see a list of commits that are more recent than what I got as results from my API call.

What am I missing? Should I try a different `refPrefix` or `orderBy` argument? I have already tried "master" as the `refPrefix`, but faced the same problem.

Comment: Learned so much in the last few days about GraphQL that I summarized my endeavor with a post on Medium: https://medium.com/@fabiomolinar/using-githubs-graphql-to-retrieve-a-list-of-repositories-their-commits-and-some-other-stuff-ccbbb4e96d78

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just realized that what I was looking for is a field which exists in the `Repository` object called `defaultBranchRef`. Using this field I was able to retrieve the data I was looking for.

My query now looks like this:

```graphql
... on Repository{
    defaultBranchRef{
        target{
            ... on Commit{
                history(first:10){
                    edges{
                        node{
                            ... on Commit{
                                committedDate
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are also interested in getting the latest commits for all branches (not just the default branch), you can request reference with prefix `refs/heads/` :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "bertrandmartel", name: "callflow-workshop") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", orderBy: {direction: DESC, field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE}, first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on Ref {
            name
            target {
              ... on Commit {
                history(first: 2) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      ... on Commit {
                        committedDate
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your case using `refs/` also gave you tag ref.

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22callflow-workshop%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20refs(refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2F%22%2C%20orderBy%3A%20%7Bdirection%3A%20DESC%2C%20field%3A%20TAG_COMMIT_DATE%7D%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Ref%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%202)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20committedDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: can you please tell me what would be the base URL for this?

Comment: @anjujo For the Github GQL API? If so, here it is:

https://api.github.com/graphql

Comment: The request is blocked in the link.

Comment: [Repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/#repository) doesn't have a `refs` field...?

Comment: @detly the missing refs tag/field could be because your link refers to gitlab and not github.