# GitHub Rest API similar git rev-list command

Tags: git, github

i get all commits of a repo with:

```
curl  -I -k -u ${api_user}:${api_token} "${api_url}/commits?sha=${api_branch}&per_page=1" | sed -n '/^[Ll]ink:/ s/.*"next".*page=\([0-9]*\).*"last".*/\1/p'
```

Is there a similar way for git rev-list with the GitHub Rest API and curl?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit confused: are you looking for a `git rev-list` command that does what your `curl` does, or are you looking for a `curl` operation that does what `git rev-list` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GitHub API v3 Commits API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#commits) is the closest:

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits
```

It could be the very same you are using, depending on what `${api_url}`.
Like [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list), it includes a commit reference from which the list starts.
And a path, to only list commits modifying the given `<paths>`.

It would not, howver, allow more complex commit specification, like `git rev-list foo bar ^baz`, which lists all the commits which are reachable from `foo` or `bar`, but not from `baz`.

For that, you would need a [GraphQL query](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), using [Commit object](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#commit), like in [those] [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56401516/6309).[6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48285888/6309)

Comment: okay, maybe i can get all commits with curl and extracting the commits who have 2+ parents?

Comment: @RomanBürkle Yes: any commit reachable from the starting point will be listed, including commits with two+ parents.